# Pause GoogleMap SupportMapFragment / Stop it from being able to be controlled

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments

I've got a GoogleMap, generated by a SupportMapFragment class. Sometimes, I have another fragment as an overlay, with some details about specific places. However, I can control the GoogleMap through the fragment with the details. How would I pause the GoogleMap / Stop it from being able to be controlled. What functions / flow interruption / other techniques am I looking for?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` in the overlay fragment. If you return `true` it will signal that the event has been consumed and stop the propagation through the lower views.